# Problem Binding Commands to TreeViewItem using MVVMLight

Tags: mvvm, binding, command, mvvm-light, treeviewitem

I'm trying to use MVVMLight to bind a TreeViewItem Selected event to a command.

The TreeViewItem's are defined in a HierarchicalDataTemplate so I cannot add Interaction.Triggers (as shown below)

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            x:Key="TreeViewItemTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ChildReportViewModels}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">
                    <MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadReportCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

How else can I add the EventTrigger to each TreeViewItem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot about this question.

For future ref, here's the solution I used...

Instead of trying to bind the EventToCommand to the Selected event of the TreeView,
I bound it to the MouseLeftButtonUpEvent of the TextBlock declared in the HierarchicalDataTemplate for TreeViewItems.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
   x:Key="TreeViewItemTemplate"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ChildReportViewModels}"
   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContainerStyle}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">        
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
               <gs_cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadPublicationCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not much knowledge about MVVMLight and especially about EventTrigger.

But since there is no answer to your qestion yet the codeplex article [TreeViewWithViewModel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) might help. It shows how to bind to SelectedItem and IsExpanded Properties in a wpf-treeview and how these can be used to implement load on demand in the treeview.